# Django - effective method to check if one user follows another user (many-to-many relations)

Tags: python-3.x, django, model, many-to-many

Basically I'm implementing pretty straightforward feature - in which one user might go to another user profile page and follow/unfollow him.

In order to steer the user interface logic I'd like to know if one user already follows another user (or not).

I implemented a method in django that works, but I think it's rather nasty. Any suggestions how this query could be simplified with Django ORM queries?

Thank you for your suggestions!

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    follows = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank = True, null = True, symmetrical=False, related_name="followers")
    pass

    def serialize(self):
        return{
        "followsCount" : self.follows.all().count(),
        "followersCount": self.followers.all().count()
        }
    
    def checkFollows(self, followCandidate ):
        # basically it checks if user of the application follows a candidate which profile is he viewing by iterating through a collection of users that he follows.
        q = self.follows.all()
        for item in q:
            if item == followCandidate:
                return True
        return False
```

Comment: I'm almost positive you can do `return followCandidate in self.follows.all()` .. or you could just do a filter, `return True if self.follows.filter(user=followCandidate).count() != 0 else False`

Comment: Cheers @Nealium, return `followCandidate in self.follows.all()` was what I was looking for!

Comment: Sweet!- glad it worked! Upon more thought, It might be a better idea to use the filter method, cause it forces the DB to do all the work instead of Python.. and DBs are specifically designed to do such crunching, just my 2 cents!